# How to get wildcard portion of filename in Bash

Tags: bash

This question may have already been asked, but I don't know how to word it well.  I'm new to bash scripting...

Suppose I have a bunch of files in a directory with names like:

```
file1_pre.ext
file2_pre.ext
file3_pre.ext
different_tmp.ext
```

I can use a use a wildcard to filter the files of interest:

```
for f in *_pre.ext
do
   echo $f
done
```

But how do I parse/extract the prefixes so that I can get strings `file1`, `file2`, etc. to use as filenames for something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`${f%_pre.ext}` will expand to the value of `f` with the final `_pre.ext` removed.

There are several kinds of string manipulation that you can do in a parameter expansion with `${varname<SomeOperator>args}`. The `%` operator removes a trailing string. It takes a wildcard argument so you cand do things like `${f%_*}` to remove everything after the underscore. If you double the `%` as in `${f%%_*}` it removes the longest match, so you'd kill everythingg after the *first* underscore. The single `%` does the shortest match, so it would remove everything after the *last* underscore. With `%_pre.ext` it doesn't make a difference since we're looking for an exact match.

The `#` and `##` operators are like `%` and `%%` but work on the beginning of the string instead of the end.

Another commonly used example is the `:-` operator which substitutes a default value if the variable is empty.

Also, `${foo}` with no operator is another way of writing `$foo` but can help you out sometimes, when you want to put some text immediately after the variable's value:

```
echo $foobar   # oops, looks for variable called "foobar"
echo ${foo}bar # the value of variable "foo" then literal "bar"
```

For a full list, see the "Parameter Expansion" section of any shell man page.

Comment: @mrKelley see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#AEN22568. The short of it: to perform operations on a variable value (or, generally, to make a variable reference visually more distinctive), enclose its name in `{}`; within that, apply operations such as `%`, which, in the case at hand, strips `_pre.ext`from the *back* of the variable value.